# Is a language case sensitive

Tags: .htaccess

This is my first time in htaccess file or language , I have a samll dude , generaly htaccess is case sensitive.

For Example : 
 `Require valid-user` is equal to `require valid-user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) says:

> Directives in the configuration files are case-insensitive, but arguments to directives are often case sensitive

Therefore there is no difference between `Require` and `require`.

Comment: Thanks your help .

Answer (score 3):

As stated in documentation Directives are case insensitive but arguments to these directives are sensitive.

Reference :https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html

Comment: Is very clarivying .